# Как передать параметр в конструктор?

Tags: java, libgdx, конструктор

Только осваиваю программирование, и возник такой вопрос:
Есть некий класс Plane, в котором есть 3 текстуры и нужно выбрать случайную.
И есть главный класс Main, в котором нужно в определенный момент поменять эту текстуру.
Вот что у меня есть:

```
public class Plane extends Sprite {

private Array<TextureRegion> colorArray;
private TextureRegion color;
public TextureRegion redPlane;
public TextureRegion bluePlane;
public TextureRegion greenPlane;



public Plane(TextureRegion color) {
    redPlane = ResourceManager.getInstance().getTextureRegion("planeRed");
    greenPlane = ResourceManager.getInstance().getTextureRegion("planeGreen");
    bluePlane = ResourceManager.getInstance().getTextureRegion("planeBlue");
    colorArray = new Array<TextureRegion>();
    this.color = color;

}

public void randomColor(){
    colorArray.addAll(redPlane,greenPlane,bluePlane);
    color = colorArray.random();
}
```

В главном классе:

```
private Plane plane;
...
plane = new Plane();
...
plane.randomColor();
```

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос -- вы спрашиваете про конструктор, но в своем коде вы уже описали конструктор с параметром. С другой стороны, не очень понятно, зачем вам констроуктор с параметром -- вашу задачу вроде бы должен решать ваш метод `randomColor()`. Только что это за метод вы вызываете: `colorArray.random()`? У стандартных массивов нет такого метода. Если вы хотите получить случайный элемент массива, то надо делать так: `java.util.Random rand = new Random(); color = array[rand.nextInt(array.length)]`. rand можно (и обычно лучше) создавать отдельно, например, в конструкторе.

Comment: Если вы хотели спросить, как вызывать конструкторы с параметром -- так точно также, как любой другой метод с параметром: `MyClass instance = new MyClass(parameter);`

Comment: Например, классический способ открытия входного текстового файла: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File.txt"));`. Здесь конструктору `BufferedReader` передается в качестве параметра объект класса `FileReader`, созданный вызовом конструктора `new FileReader("File.txt")`

Comment: Да, вопрос сформулировал не очень, согласен)
colorArray.random() работает, это libgdx. 
Всё работает, отрисовывается, но получается, что просто при запуске случайный цвет появляется, а мне нужно в определенный момент. Выходит так, что randomColor() я вызываю в классе Plane (здесь не показано, уже поменял код) и результат такой, как я описал выше. А если вызывать в главном классе, то я не знаю что передать 
plane = new Plane( !! сюда!!  );

Comment: Я все равно не понял, что вы хотите. Вы можете сделать коснтруктор баз параметра, который создает обект со случайным цветом, можете задавать определенный цвет при создании, передавая цвет в конструктор в качестве параметра, и можете менять цвет на случайно выбранный, вызывая `randomColor()` тогда, когда вам нужно. Что именно не получается?

Comment: я, в принципе, разобрался, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Может быть, тогда вы переформулируете свой вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, о чем идет речь, и чтобы кто-нибудь мог дать грамотный ответ на него? Это могло бы пригодиться следующим поколениям. А то в таком виде вопрос хочется минусовать, и наверняка кто-нибудь не удержится..